# Reactive Forms: Submit form programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I haven't found any solution to submit my form out of the controller in Angular 5. I would like to submit the form on focusout, whereas I only have the FormControl (because it's a dynamic, nested form out of several components).
I have the following code:

```
  execFocusout(formControlToUse: FormConrol) {

    if ( this.submitOn === 'focusout') {
      console.log('Focusout triggered. Value: ' + formControlToUse.value);

      formControlToUse.root.submit(); // doesn't work
    }
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.